# how to determine if a plugin is installed in wordpress or not with php code

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have created 2 related plugins in wordpress individually, and now I want to redirect page to different location depends on the plugins that are installed. I dont know how should I determine that the plugin is installed or not.

```
function pr_st_loginRedirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    global $user;
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) 
        {
            return home_url()."/wp-admin/";
        } 
        else if ( in_array( 'manager', $user->roles ) )
        {
          if(first plugin is installed)// what should I write in if statement?
            {
                return home_url()."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=creat_mysite_emp_list_entry";
            }
            else
            {
                return  home_url()."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=students_std_list_students";
            }  
        }
        else if ( in_array( 'student', $user->roles ) )
        {
            return home_url()."/wp-admin/admin.php?page=students_std_show_report_card_to_student";
        }
    }                          
}

add_filter("login_redirect", "pr_st_loginRedirect", 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (is_plugin_active('myplugin/myplugin.php'))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
if( function_exists( 'specific_plugin_function' ) )
```

or

```
if( class_exists( 'SpecificPluginClass' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks if a plugin is activated.

NOTE: defined in wp-admin/includes/plugin.php, so this is only available from within the admin pages, and any references to this function must be hooked to admin_init or a later action. If you want to use this function from within a template, you will need to manually require plugin.php, an example is below Usage

```
Admin area 
<?php
/**
 * Detect plugin. For use in Admin area only.
 */
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {
  //plugin is activated
} 


Front end 
<?php
/**
 * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
 */
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

// check for plugin using plugin name
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {
  //plugin is activated
}
```

[Function Reference is plugin active](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active)